# Beautifoulsoup scraping google

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape google knowledge panel to retrieve the name of drugs if they do not appear in google search. For instance if I look for "Buscopan" in Google, the appearing webpage looks like this:
[image]

Now, what I am trying to do with the code shown is take the term "Scopolamina-N-butilbromuro" in the knowledge panel but am actually unable to retrieve it in the html code once I inspect the element. To be precise. The code I am implementing together with the error message is as follows:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

## URL

url = "https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q="+"buscopan"+"&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8"

```
# Sending HTTP request 
req = requests.get(url) 
  
# Pulling HTTP data from internet 
sor = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")  
   
temp = sor.find("h2", class_= "qrShPb kno-ecr-pt PZPZlf mfMhoc hNKfZe").text


print(temp)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-ef5599a1a1fc> in <module>
     13 # Finding temperature in Celsius
     14 #temp = sor.find("h2", class_='qrShPb').text
---> 15 temp = sor.find("h2", class_= "qrShPb kno-ecr-pt PZPZlf mfMhoc hNKfZe").text
     16 
     17 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I think the bit of html code I need to look at is the following:

```html
<h2 class="qrShPb kno-ecr-pt PZPZlf mfMhoc hNKfZe" data-local-attribute="d3bn" data-attrid="title" data-ved="2ahUKEwjujfLcgO7rAhWKjosKHSiBAFEQ3B0oATASegQIEBAL"></h2>
```

Of course the rest of the html code is in the picture reported, but if you need a bigger version, please, do not esitate!

Any suggestion?

Thank you,

Federico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get correct result page from Google search, specify `User-Agent` HTTP header. For example:

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


params = {
    'q': 'buscopan',    # <-- change to your keyword
    'hl': 'it'          # <-- change to `en` for english results
}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}
url = 'https://www.google.com/search'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('h2[data-attrid="title"]').text)
```

Prints:

```
Scopolamina-N-butilbromuro
```

Comment: Thank you a loot @Andrej Kesley. May I also ask you what are headers. Sorry but I am not very into Beautfulsoup. Thank you again!

Comment: @NutarelliFederico HTTP headers are part of HTTP protocol (BeautifulSoup is just a parser). When `requests` is making a HTTP request, it sends several HTTP headers. Among them is `User-Agent` that identifies the browser. More about HTTP headers for example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers

Comment: I see. Thank you a lot again! Very helpful comments

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, to **[Andrej Kesely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63924347/15164646)** solution, you can use third-party [Google Knowledge Graph API](https://serpapi.com/knowledge-graph) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan. Check out the [Playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=Buscopan&gl=us&hl=en) to test.

Code to integrate and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Search-Knowledge-Graph-python-serpapi#main.py):

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
    "q": "Buscopan",
    "google_domain": "google.com",
    "hl": "en",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

title = results['knowledge_graph']['title']
print(title)
```

Output:

```
Butylscopolamine
```

Part of JSON Knowledge Graph output:

```json
"knowledge_graph": {
  "title": "Butylscopolamine",
  "type": "Medication",
  "description": "Hyoscine butylbromide, also known as scopolamine butylbromide and sold under the brandname Buscopan among others, is an anticholinergic medication used to treat crampy abdominal pain, esophageal spasms, renal colic, and bladder spasms. It is also used to improve respiratory secretions at the end of life.",
  "source": {
    "name": "Wikipedia",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyoscine_butylbromide"
  },
  "formula": "C₂₁H₃₀BrNO₄",
  "molar_mass": "440.371 g/mol",
  "chem_spider_id": "16736107",
  "trade_name": "Buscopan, others",
  "pub_chem_cid": "6852391",
  "ch_ebi_id": "32123",
  "people_also_search_for": "Scopolamine, Metamizole, MORE"
}
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.